# Mark row for deleting using checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, checkbox, methods

I have this inbox or mails which I needed to mark using checkbox for multiple deletions. The problem is that when I click the checkbox it always go to method read() because of onclick inside the  tag. All I want is simple marking. Please see the code below:

```
@foreach ($messages as $message)    
  <tr onclick="document.location='{{route('account.message.read', array($message->id))}}'">
     <td> <input type="checkbox" name="msg" value="{{$message->id}}"></td>
     <td><strong>{{Str::words($message->subject, 5, '...')}}</strong> {{Str::words($message->message, 20, '...')}}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Now how can I mark each row without going inside that method? I am a newbie btw.

Comment: If you want to select multiple elements then remove that `onclick` parameter from the `checkbox` tag. For multiple deletions, create another button and add the modified `onclick` parameter, which deletes all the marked elements, to that.

Comment: @CrakC on the code i posted there is no onclick parameter inside the checkbox. I didn't get it sorry. I want to mark each row and delete all the marked row at once.

Comment: Ok so I got it wrong. However, you have included an `onclick` parameter for the bounding `tr` tag which means any element inside it would trigger the `onclick` event when clicked. Try a workaround by adding the `onclick`parameter to a `div` or `span` or `p` that lies next to the `checkbox` and contains, say, the subject of the email.

Comment: @CrackC thank you, your solution works. There is another solution made by Norlihazmey Ghazali in this page which I find would fit to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to is attach handler to `checkbox` and use [`stopPropagation`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) from bubbling up into trees, see below example :

**HTML**

Supposed we have table rows with `onclick` inline javascript and inside it have `input`:

```
<table>
  <tr onclick="return alert('Hai')">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />Click Me
    </td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

And here the handler :

```
$('input').click(function(e){
  // normally if we removed this line of code
  // alert will getting called as checkbox is checked/unchecked
  // was inside table rows
  // but with this propagation, we disabled it 
  // from bubbling up into tree
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/t2j8904o/)

Comment: thank you this solution works well. Exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

you could put the onclick inside the  tags excluding the checkbox cell

otherwise you could call an actual onclick function while capturing the click event and check that x is greater than lets say 50px!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('emailRow1').addEventListener("click",function(e){
 var x=e.pageX-this.offsetLeft;
 if(x>50){
  rowClicked();
 }
 },true);
</script>
```

```html
<table><tbody><tr id='emailRow1'><td style="width:50px;">This area wont trigger onclick</td><td>I trigger onclick</td><td>i trigger onclick</td>
```

Then you can set custom parameters on your  object and recall them using this.customPropertyName to determine what row was clicked! hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. that would work but I will keep on repeating to put the onclick in each <td>.. I have more <td> to put on that row like the subject and the sender of the message.

Comment: I edited my answer. I think the code above would help make the scalability of your page better by implementing cutom properties into your html or JScript and set your onclicks through javascript rather than as an HREF but as a general answer to the question at hand @Norilihazmey has the simplest answer to your question

Comment: thank you. your answer could work and it is good. I agree with you that Norilihazmey has simple solution.